# Send JSON body in GET request via Retrofit 2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Do you know a clean way to send JSON in GET query with Retrofit 2 ? This is not working :

```
@GET
fun getProducts(
  @Body search: SearchRequest
): Call<List<Product>>
```

Comment: put your full code. Normally @Body works with POST

Comment: can you consume the service with soap or postman? you can use the application https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui/ or https://www.postman.com/

Comment: yes but not working with a GET and i'm using POST to create a Product...

Comment: Can you show your request in Postman or in cURL so that we could know how that can be achieved?